# F#: How to avoid "[FS0988] Main module of program is empty: nothing will happen when it is run" in Tests Project?

Tags: compilation, f#, compiler-warnings

I have a .NET solution with the projects below:

- `Console`: Console .NET Core 2.2
- `Domain`: .NET Standard 2.0
- `Domain.Tests`: Console .NET Core 2.2 (XUnit)
- `Infrastructure`: .NET Standard 2.0

My `Domain.Tests.fsproj` is defined as:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>

        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
        <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="FsCheck" Version="3.0.0-alpha4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="Dsl.fs" />
      <Compile Include="OpenAccountTests.fs" />
      <Compile Include="CloseAccountTests.fs" />
      <Compile Include="DepositCashTests.fs" />
      <Compile Include="WithdrawCashTests.fs" />
      <Compile Include="WireMoneyTests.fs" />
      <Compile Include="RequestAddressChangeTests.fs" />
      <Compile Include="RequestEmailChangeTests.fs" />
      <Compile Include="RequestPhoneNumberChangeTests.fs" />
      <Compile Include="ValidateAddressChangeTests.fs" />
      <Compile Include="ValidateEmailChangeTests.fs" />
      <Compile Include="ValidatePhoneNumberChangeTests.fs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Domain\Domain.fsproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

But when compiling the solution I have the following warning:

> `ValidatePhoneNumberChangeTests.fs`(102, 35): [FS0988] Main module of program is empty: nothing will happen when it is run

I checked [that answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159387/how-to-resolve-main-module-of-program-is-empty-nothing-will-happen-when-it-is) and adding `do()` at the end of the last file of `Domain.Tests`: `ValidatePhoneNumberChangeTests.fs` didn't do anything.

What can I do to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

This specifies the Domain.Tests project as an executable

If you only need it to be a class library then change it to

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

If you simply want to remove the warning you can add a main method by either adding this at the end of `ValidatePhoneNumberChangeTests.fs` or in a `Program.fs` at the end of the compilation order

```
[<EntryPoint>] 
let main argv =
    0
```

Comment: it needs to be `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>` for running tests (at least this is my experience in Rider)

Comment: In that case you can fake a main method by either adding this at the end of `ValidatePhoneNumberChangeTests.fs` or in a `Program.fs` at the end of the compilation order

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv =
         0

Comment: `Program.fs` at the end of the compilation order with `[<EntryPoint>] let main argv = 0` did the trick
Thanks!

Comment: I thought it was the `<OutputType>` property that specified the project as an executable or a class library. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019 it defaults to `Library`, but I've seen multiple Stack Overflow questions asking why MSBuild was building an exe instead of a dll when there was no `<OutputType>`, so maybe try adding `<OutputType>Library</OutputType>` to your .fsproj and see what that does? (And if so, you'll want to remove the `Program.fs` file as that's not needed in a DLL).

Answer (score 10):

@rmunn is on the right track in the comments. `<OutputType>` defaults to `Library` when `TargetFramework` is `netstandardXX` or `net4XX`, and `Exe` when `TargetFramework` is `netcoreappXX`.

Setting `<OutputType>Library</OutputType>` is IMO the best way to fix this, rather than adding an entry point that won't be called.

Comment: That being said, if I am changing to Library + .NET Standard, Rider does no longer run the unit tests =/
(so at the end of the day this might be more of a Rider issue)

Comment: I have just come across this exact issue, it seems adding <OutputType>Library</OutputType> aught to solve this issue, but it does not.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the Program.fs and OutputType (it doesn't work for me as well). Set GenerateProgramFile to true in PropertyGroup like that:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <GenerateProgramFile>true</GenerateProgramFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

cheers!